# How to set the arguments of tf.extract_image_patches

Tags: image, tensorflow, extract, patch, stride

I want to extract image patches from the input image in my tensorflow model. 
Let's say the input image is `[batch, in_width, in_height, channels]`, I want to output `[no_patches, patch_width, patch_height, channels]`. `no_patches` are the total number of patches can be extracted from the `input_image`.

I found out that `tf.extract_image_patches` can do the job. 
However, I don't understand the difference of the arguments `strides` and `rates`.

Can someone explain how to use the above function to do the work?

Answer (score 1):

`strides` is about the movement of the window on your data.

`rates` is about how 'spread out' the window is.

For instance, if you use `strides = [1,5,5,1]` your window jumps by 5 pixels in both the 1st and 2nd dimension. If you use `rates = [1,1,1,1]` your window is 'compact', meaning that all the pixels are contiguous. If you use `rates = [1,1,2,1]`, then your window spreads out in the 2nd dimension and takes a pixel every 2.

Example with `ksizes = [1,3,2,1]` (ignore strides for now): on the left we use , `rates = [1,1,1,1]`, in the middle we use `rates = [1,1,2,1]`, on the right we use `rates = [1,2,2,1]` :

```
*  *  3  4  5          *  2  *  4  5          *  2  *  4  5 
*  *  8  9  10         *  7  *  9  10         6  7  8  9  10
*  *  13 14 15         *  12 *  14 15         *  12 *  14 15
16 17 18 19 20         16 17 18 19 20         16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25         21 22 23 24 25         *  22 *  24 25
```